# Ошибка - TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Tags: python, python-3.x, join

```
def scetcik(длина_колво):
    длина = int(длина_колво.split(" ")[0]) #длина строки
    колво = int(длина_колво.split(" ")[1]) #количество вариантов чисел
    test = input().split(" ")
    for f in test:
        f = int(f) #str в int
    test.sort() #сортирует в порядке возрастания
    res = []
    plus = 0
    ans = "*" * колво
    answer = list(ans)
    for j in test:
        try: #если число уже встречалось
            x = res.index(j)
            answer[x] = int(answer[x])+1
        except ValueError: #если число встречается впервые
            res.append(j)
            answer.insert(plus,1)
            answer.pop(plus+1)
            plus = plus+1
    print(" ".join(answer)) #пишет ответ (ОШИБКА)
scetcik(input())
```

Comment: работает весь код кроме предпоследней строчки(join)

Comment: никак не могу понять в чем ошибка

Comment: код написан для задания на сайте http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/array-counters--ru

Comment: Совет: почитайте о словарях (dictionary) в Python и о том как ими пользоваться. А этот код проще забыть и переписать "с нуля"

Comment: В `answer` есть `int` переменные, а `.join` ожидает что только строковые будут

Comment: а если сделать так:

Comment: for sss in answer:       sss = str(sss)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

В `answer` есть `int` переменные, а `.join` ожидает что только строковые будут, поэтому замените:

```
print(" ".join(answer))
```

на

```
print(" ".join(str(x) for x in answer))
```

Или на (функциональный стиль):

```
print(" ".join(map(str, answer)))
```

*А так, как посторонний, мне было бы проще узнать всю задачу и с нуля переписать – в чужом коде, не зная темы очень сложно разбираться*

Answer (score 4):

[Эту задачу](http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/array-counters--ru) можно решить гораздо проще используя словарь:

```
In [141]: def my_counter(lst):
     ...:     res = {}
     ...:     for x in lst:
     ...:         res[x] = res[x] + 1 if x in res else 1
     ...:     return res
     ...:

In [142]: test = '1 2 3 2 3 1 1 1 1 3'

In [143]: res = my_counter(test.split())

In [144]: print(res)
{'1': 5, '2': 2, '3': 3}

In [145]: print(*res.values())
5 2 3
```

Можно конечно еще проще:

```
In [150]: from collections import Counter

In [151]: c = Counter(test.split())

In [152]: print(*c.values())
5 2 3
```

но я думаю от вас ожидали собственной реализации

Comment: +1, за разбирание проблемы автора и реализации :)

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо! Проблему автора как раз вы разобрали, а я попытался показать ему другой путь ;-)